# PageSpeed app.js and app.css blocking render

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I am optimising my site for PageSpeed Insight from google and only have 1 issue left where app.js and app.css are blocking render.

As I am using webpack I have no control over this as it generates index.html file and pushes scripts there, I know for app.js I could use something like `<script async>` but how do I tell webpack to add it?

Also how can I overcome this issue with css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) you can add `async` attribute via its [`script-ext-html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin) extension.

For css read this well explained [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css).